# How to get date value from one date input field and put it to other date field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, datepicker

I have two input fields of type 'date'.I want to take value from one input field and send it to other using javascript.

```
<form>
    <input type='date' id='field1'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<input type='date' id='field2'>
```

Now when the user submits the date from 'field1',how would the same date value go in 'field2'?
Sorry for bad description and grammar.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Here's my code, and my explanation will follow:

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type='date' id='field1'>
   <input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick="setDate()">    
</form>
   <input type='date' id='field2'>
```

Javascript:

```
function setDate(){
var x = document.getElementById('field1').value; //"Pulling" the value entered 
document.getElementById('field2').value= x; // Replacing the value at field2 with the defined value x
```

Explanation:

So what's happening here is, we first placed an onclick function in the submit field, meaning it will only run when the user clicks submit. It will call the function "setDate()". setDate() has 2 lines of code, the first will search the document for an id "field1" and gets it's value and saves it as variable x. The second takes that saved value and places it at a place with id "field2"

Hope this helps, and don't forget to "check" the right answer!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Not all questions can or should be answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, you can get input that id is `field1` and set the value to input that id is `field2`, just like following:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const field1Value = document.getElementById('field1').value;
  document.getElementById('field2').value = field1Value;  
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type='date' id='field1'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<input type='date' id='field2'>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Not all questions can or should be answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

It only took me a couple minutes to find a couple answers for this question.

In theory, it's simple.

1. Get the value of the date input
2. Store it in a variable
3. Copy it into a date input.

```js
function copy(){
    var input = document.getElementById('field1').value;
    document.getElementById('field2').value = input;
}
```

```html
<input type='date' id='field1'>
<button onclick='copy()'>Submit</button>

<input type='date' id='field2'>
```

Comment: Pure javascript by the way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Not all questions can or should be answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Always trying to help though. Alright, I'll keep that in mind.